# How to use Polymer animations?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polymer-1.0

Is there any documentation I am missing regarding Polymer animations? I'm trying to use `transform-animation` but I don't know where to start. Tried checking GitHub and the examples on Neon-animations but they seem way too complex for me when I just wanna learn the very basics.

I wanna start by expanding a divs height over time when a click on the div occurs.

Thanks!

Comment: The best places to start are [this](https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/using-neon-animations) documentation from the Polymer Elements catalog and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lwvi1u4XXzc) excellent tutorial video.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for! Post as an answer and I will approve it! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best places to start are [this](https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/using-neon-animations) documentation from the Polymer Elements catalog and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lwvi1u4XXzc) excellent tutorial video from Google.

Comment: Watched the video and it was really great! Thank you! Do you know if there's any way to make animations "persist" their value? If I scale my div height I want elements below to also move while the animation is playing.

Comment: So you want the elements in your div to also scale? They should be doing that already as they do in the video.

Comment: No I meant, stuff that aren't inside the div but outside the div. For example, if i resize the comment-div here on SO the text below will move. But if I do this with animations that won't happen according to the video because animations don't actually "persist" the changes.

Comment: @user2422321 That should be handled by your css layout. Use relative position instead of giving absolute coordinates for positioning and browser will automatically push down divs below it.